# J Unit Test problems?

Tags: java, junit4

Here is the code for the employee superclass that i need to test.

```
public abstract class Employee {
    protected int id; 
    protected double weeklyPay;

public Employee(int id)
    {
        this.id=id;
    }

public void setId(int id)
    {
        this.id=id;
    }
public int getId() 
    {
        return id;
    }
public String toString() 
    {
        return id+"has a weekly pay of "+weeklyPay;
    }
public double getWeeklyPay() 
    {
        return weeklyPay;
    }
```

Here is the code of the ManagerClass

```
public class Manager extends Employee

public Manager(int id, double weeklyPay) 
    {
        super(id);
        super.weeklyPay=weeklyPay;
    }

public String toString() 
    {
        return "Manager " + super.toString();
    }
```

Here is the part of the manager JUnit Test that doesnt work

```
public void testToString() {
        assertEquals("Manager 1has a weekly pay of 42", new Manager(1, 42).toString());
```

This is the failure message that i get     org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected <...s a weekly pay of 42[]> but was <...s a weekly pay of 42[.0]>

Comment: look at the code: what do you expect that new Manager(1,42).toString() will deliver?

Comment: Could I suggest you put specifically what the problem is? Other than that junit will tell you why the test is failing from there you need to determine is the test wrong or the code.

Comment: This is the failure i get         org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected <...s a weekly pay of 42[]> but was <...s a weekly pay of 42[.0]>

Comment: It is simply the output of toString is NOT ".... of 42", it is ".... of 42.0".  No one can help u to fix that as no one knows what is the correct behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Because you have your weeklyPay as a double, the toString method is printing it as 42.0 and because you are comparing it to a string, it is not evaluating the 42 in the string.

Try this:

```
assertEquals("Manager 1has weekly pay of 42.0", new Manager(1, 42).toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

This would work:

```
assertEquals("Manager 1has a weekly pay of 42.0", new Manager(1, 42).toString());
```

You have weeklyPay as `double` in your super class. So it prints 42.0 , not 42.

**Another way:**

Add another constructor:

```
 public Employee(int id, double wP) {
    this.id = id;
    this.weeklyPay = wP;
    }
```

Then, from manager:

```
 public Manager(int id, double weeklyPay) {
    super(id, weeklyPay);
    }
```

Following prints : **Manager 1has a weekly pay of 20.0**

```
 @Test
    public void tt() {
    Manager m = new Manager(1, 20);
    System.out.println(m);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

from the way the classes are written I would expect this to pass.

```
assertEquals("Manager 1has a weekly pay of 42", new Manager(1, 42).toString());
```

Comment: Sorry BevynQ, your code does not pass the JUnit test. Do you need anything else that i need to tell you?

Comment: This is the failure message that i get     org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected <...s a weekly pay of 42[]> but was <...s a weekly pay of 42[.0]>

Comment: Then the code should be `assertEquals("Manager 1has a weekly pay of 42.0", new Manager(1, 42).toString());`. @user1873746, why don't you try to understand what the code is doing ?

Comment: Thanks to your code, now i understand what was going wrong. This is my first actual jUnit test case. give a brother a break.

Comment: @user1873746 It is hard to ask people to give u a break if you are not doing your part.  It seems to us (at least me) that you are not even trying to understand the basics of JUnit.